# Java input and output stream from file path

Tags: java, inputstream

How does one use a specified file path rather than a file from the resource folder as an input or output stream? This is the class I have and I would like to read from a specific file path instead of placing the txt file in the resources folder in IntelliJ. Same for an output stream. Any help rendered would be appreciated thanks.

**Input Stream**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Example02 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // STEP 1: obtain an input stream to the data

        // obtain a reference to resource compiled into the project
        InputStream is = Example02.class.getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");

        // convert to useful form
        Scanner in = new Scanner(is);

        // STEP 2: do something with the data stream
        // read contents
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String line = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        // STEP 3: be polite, close the stream when done!
        // close file
        in.close();
    }
}
```

**Output stream**

```
import java.io.*;

public class Example03
{
    public static void main(String []args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // create/attach to file to write too
        // using the relative filename will cause it to create the file in
        // the PROJECT root
        File outFile = new File("info.txt");

        // convert to a more useful writer
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

        //write data to file
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
            out.println("" + i + " x 5 = " + i*5);

        //close file - required!
        out.close();            
    }
}
```

Comment: FileInputStream

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Preferred way for getting InputStream is [java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Path)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newInputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

```
try(final InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/path/to/file")) {
    //Do something with is
}
```

Same for OutputStream [Files.newOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newOutputStream(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...))

```
try(final OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("/path/to/file")) {
    //Do something with os
}
```

Generally, here is [official tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) to working with IO.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to define the path you want to read the file from, absolute path like so:

```
String absolutePath = "C:/your-dir/yourfile.txt"
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(absolutePath);
```

It's similar for writing the file as well:

```
String absolutePath = "C:/your-dir/yourfile.txt"
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(absolutePath));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a file object as:

```
File input = new File("C:\\[Path to file]\\file.txt");
```